# PyPI Projects Safe 0r Not

Tags: python, pypi

Install some packages from PyPI projects like `colorama`, `pytz`., but I wondered if every project in the PyPI project is safe to use. If not how to choose that. Example now I want to experiment, python project to executable file(.exe). For that, I just Google for solutions. Many people suggest [pyinstaller 4.7](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/). But it is trustable. If that so, how can I choose any other package in PyPI Projects

Comment: PyInstaller is very trustable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37956106/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpypi%5D+safe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46270513/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpypi%5D+security

Comment: Thank you, @phd for your reply. For the safer side, I need to read & understand the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are PIP packages curated? Is it safe to install them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236366/are-pip-packages-curated-is-it-safe-to-install-them)